# MySQL integration with C# (Windows Forms) not working?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, winforms

I am making a Windows Forms application using C#
I have a running MySQL db with the help of WAMP. I have referenced the MySQL dll's in my project. I am not receiving any errors from the console or within the code itself. My problem, however, is that my SQL-command does not work and I have no idea why...

Here is the code:

```
private void ConnectToDB(String title, String content, String price)
    {
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testing.customers (itemTitle, itemContent, itemPrice) VALUES('" + title + "', '" + content + "', '" + price + "');";
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        connect.Close();
    }

private void db_connection()
    {
        try
        {
            conn = "Server=localhost;Database=testinbg;Uid=TheAdmin;Pwd=dsa67as7d66asd;";
            connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            connect.Open();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I have given the user 'TheAdmin' all privileges? Am I missing something? :)

Comment: I do not see that You are executing the query. Use cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to *execute* your query:

```
  cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery();
```

The implementation

```
  conn = "Server=localhost;Database=testinbg;Uid=TheAdmin;Pwd=dsa67as7d66asd;";
  ...
  // Wrap IDisposable (i.e. MySqlConnection) into "using"
  using (var connect = new MySqlConnection(conn)) 
  {
    connect.Open();    
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()) 
    {
      cmd.Connection = connect;
      cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO...";    
      cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Might be worth adding a recommendation of using parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection?

Answer (score 1):

You're not executing your query. Also, your query is currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterized queries to prevent the aforementioned attacks. I've changed your query so it's parameterized.

```
string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO testing.customers (itemTitle, itemContent, itemPrice) VALUES(@title, @content, @price)";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = title;
        ...
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //You were missing this
    }
}
```

Read more about [SQL injection.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)